# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass - Model association problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User, Conversation, and Message model. A User has_many conversations and messages. A Conversation has_many messages, and messages belong to both users and conversations. Both the conversation and message models have a user_id column.

When I try to display the name of the user associated with a specific message I get the undefined method error.

My Conversations_controller

```
 class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @conversation = current_user.conversations.build(conversation_params)
    if @conversation.save
      save_conversation(@conversation)
      flash[:notice] = "Conversation was succesfully created"
      redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
    save_conversation(@conversation)
    @message = @conversation.messages.build
  end
```

My messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @message = current_conversation.messages.build(message_params)
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message was successfully created"
      redirect_to conversation_path(current_conversation)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Message not saved"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

     def message_params
       params.require(:message).permit(:chat, :user_id)
     end

end
```

My models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :messages
end
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And my conversation show view

```
<h1><%= @conversation.title %></h1>

<p>
  Description: <%= @conversation.description %>
</p>
<p>
    Created by: <%= @conversation.user.name %>
</p>

<% if @conversation.messages.any? %>
    <% @conversation.messages.each do |message| %>
      <%= message.chat %>
      <%= message.user.name %>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Its the message.user.name that Rails seems to take exception to. I was under the impression that because the two models are associated I could use user.name?

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can offer, please let me know if you need anything else to help.

Thanks

Comment: could you please post the specific error you are getting (the entire error message). I would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Sean the entire error message is NoMethodError in Conversations#show,  undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: from that error message, we can infer that the problem is not calling name on user, the problem is that you are trying to call name on nil.  This means that message.user is returning nil.  Try to find the reason why the message is not being associated with the user, and then i think your code should work (once that association is set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be possible because:

You're not validating the presence of a user on the message model

You may not be assigning the value of the user_id in your messages_controller, an approach I would probably follow is:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @message = current_conversation.messages.build(message_params)
    @message.user = current_user # provided you have current_user set somewher
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message was successfully created"
      redirect_to conversation_path(current_conversation)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Message not saved"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```